# SSO with putty via GSSAPI

Tags: single-sign-on, putty, gssapi

I've been trying to integrate the login to Console of Suse Linux server  using putty via Single Sign On.
To that end, I've come across two setting:

1. Allow `GSSAPI` credentials delegation in SSO; and
2. Enable the `GSSAPIaunthentiation` in Linux.

Am I missing anything else?

Comment: Doesn't this make better sense on superuser?

Comment: Hi  JoSSte ,  it is actually , we are designing a way to allow member from  DL at  windows  AD to give admin access without needing them to provide login deatails

Comment: I meant the stackexchange site superuser. SSO makes perfect sense

Comment: hi JoSSte / Team ,   as i was working on the system ,   I enabled the  domain membership of the server to the AD  by making setting changes via Yast in the  Network Services > Windows Domain membership & installed some package , now I am not able to login via root also.  Some how I disconnected NIC card & was able to login to system via root & tried disabling the settings but even after that I am not able to login to the server normally.  Could you please tell me any way how to disable / revert / set to default settings so that I can working back normally

Comment: Have a look at superuser: http://superuser.com/search?q=putty+gssapi there are several putty+ gssapi questions which appear to have answers. I think that moving your question there would give it a better chance of being answered.

Comment: Thanks JoSSte for your help.